# How is unit limit calculated?

Tags: supreme-commander

In some of the later campaign levels, it is very easy to reach the unit limit and hear that "unit limit reached" announcement. I've noticed that it's much harder to hit that limit if I try to build as much higher-tier stuff as I can.

How is the unit limit calculated? Do all structures and units count equally? What about walls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All structures and units count as one towards the unit limit (apart from walls which are 1/10 of a unit), so later on it is quite easy to hit the limit as you probably have extensive defenses and resource farms at that point.

In multiplayer/skirmish I find that it is really easy to hit the limit, hence I use mods to increase the limit. As for the campaign I believe the later missions have the same maximum level as the maximum for skirmish which is 1000 unmodded. (This is for Forged Alliance, I can't remember if it differs from the original game, but I don't think so).